# Tizen 2.3.2 push notifications

Tags: push-notification, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, wearables, samsung-gear

I'm trying to develop a watch app for the Gear S3 Frontier. I had been mistakenly testing with the Tizen emulator on Tizen 3.0, but have discovered that my push notification implementation does not work in 2.3.2 (which is what is on the S3 now). I have checked and rechecked against every example I could find, but cannot seem to receive push notifications. It works fine with 3.0, but the altered version that uses the 2.3.2 method of connecting simply never receives any notifications. The Samsung push API reports success when my server sends, but I never get anything on the watch or emulator in 2.3.2. I saw that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23954963/tizen-push-notifications-in-emulator) asks a similar questions but was never fully answered and I don't have the rep to comment on it. Does someone have a working example of this?

Comment: have you looked at https://developer.tizen.org/forums/native-application-development/customize-notifications-wearable-2.3.2-tizen-native#comment-25626 OP seemed to find the solution there....

Comment: Thanks, but that is just local notifications. I'm looking to receive remote push notifications.

Comment: Check this site for details https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/messaging/push-notification

Comment: That's the page I originally used to develop my project. It still doesn't work.

Comment: I think you have checked that two types of separate implementations available.(Type-1)Up to Tizen 2.4 &  (Type-2)Since Tizen 3.0. Your device(2.3.2) and your code(Type-1) should handshake on api usage.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I discovered an error in the logs that indicated that it was looking for the "appData" field. The documentation says that you can include EITHER "appData" or "message", but it appears that you must have BOTH present in 2.3.2. Tizen 3.0 doesn't seem to care.